# How to save data POSTed from From into database not using Form->setModel()

Tags: atk4, php

I know that's kinda simple and lame question, but still.

I have a Form which should not show all Model fields, but only some of them. That's why I can't use Form->setModel($m), because that'll automatically add all fields into Form.

So I add Model into page, then add form into page and then use form->importFields like this:

```
$m = $p->add('Model_Example');
$f = $p->add('Form');
//$f->setModel($m); // can't use this because that'll import all model fields
$f->importFields($m,array('id','description'));
$f->addSubmit('Save');
```

What I don't understand in this situation is - how to save this data in database, because $f->update() in onSubmit event will not work. Basically nothing I tried will work because Form have no associated Model (with setModel).

Answer (score 1):

How about this way?

$your_form->setModel($model,array('name','email','age'));

Comment: Check the subject of this question "...not using Form->setModel()..." :) Idea behind all this is that form->setModel automatically populates form with fields, but sometimes I want to show different fields in form populated from different and maybe even not related models or do some other stuff with values received from form POST. So, setModel can't be used in such situations. Then you have to use simple approach - like written in ATK4 documentation about form data validation.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't see the last part of your question! :( you are true.

Answer (score 1):

I have solution for mixed form. Add custom form fields in form init and manipulate with them by hooks ('afterLoad','beforeSave')
In this case you can use setModel() method

```
$form->setModel('Some_Model',array('title','description'));


class Form_AddTask extends Form {
    function init(){
        parent::init();
        $this->r=$this->addField('autocomplete/basic','contact');
        $this->r->setModel('ContactEntity_My');
    }
    function setModel($model,$actual_fields=undefined){
        parent::setModel($model,$actual_fields);
        $this->model->addHook('afterLoad',array($this,'setContactId'));
        $this->model->addHook('beforeSave',array($this,'setContactEntityId'));
        return $this->model;
    }

    // set saved value for editing
    function setContactId() {
        $this->r->set($this->model->get('contact_entity_id'));
    }
    function setContactEntityId() {
        $this->model->set('contact_entity_id',$this->get('contact'));
    }
}
```

There is a hook 'validate' as well in Form_Basic::submitted(), so you can add

```
    $this->addHook('validate',array($this,'validateCustomData'));
```

and validate your data in Form::validateCustomData()

Comment: This looks nice. Have to check that more closely.

Answer (score 0):

Why not set the fields to hidden in the model?

I.e.:

class Model_Example extends Model_Table {
    public $table='assessment';

```
function init() {
    parent::init();

    $grant->addField('hidden_field')->hidden(true);
}
```

}

And then:

```
$m = $p->add('Model_Example');
$f = $p->add('Form');
$f->setModel($m);
```

Comment: Idea behind all this is that I have a big Model with a lot of not hidden fields. Creating simple data enter form for such a big model is not good, because form will be to big to fit in 1 screen. So, I'm making all this data enter process in a "wizard" style. It's like step 1, enter 4-5 most important fields, then click Next to go to step 2, then enter 4-5 not so important fields, click Next to go to step 3, then fill next fields etc.

Comment: My last idea is to maybe use $form->setModel($m,array('field_1','field_2',...)); or something like that, but I have not tested that yet.

Comment: This is just an idea but since you can pass variables into the init() - pass a variable indicating which fields will be hidden. So basically one step 1 of the wizard send a variable into init hiding the remainder of the data and send the model inside the post and then reset the model passing a new variable hiding the rest of the fields and set that model's values to the one from the post?

Comment: One more way how to do this would be to overwrite MVCForm controller. That's actually the one who automatically call importFields() to all fields in model.

Comment: I guess in my case I'll stick to more simple approach. I know that quite a code rewriting for every step, but... I guess I'll add Model and $form->setModel('Example',array(...some fields...)) in every step. That's because I just noticed that in some steps I anyway need to load more than one Model to show in my form.
But still my original question is not fully answered. The question in general was - how to save data POSTed from form which is not related to any model into Model. It's something like $model->load($id); $model->set($form->getAllFields); $model->save() I guess.